# stricter XmlSerializer which does not allow unused nodes

Tags: c#, xml, strict, serialization

I generated C# classes based on XSD using the xsd.exe tool from the SDK. Then I can use that class to [de]serialize objects using XmlSerializer... However the serializer seems to be very forgiving.

Is it possible that I can make the serializer throw an exception in case there is  missing property or a "strange" XML node?

I think one way is to modify the setter of the property and make it validate the data (or use XSD validation)... However is there any other alternative solution for this problem ?

Comment: https://acme.newprod.econometrix.com/ClientBin/Trescreatus.Econometrix.DataVisualization.SpendAnalysis.xap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [`IXmlSerializable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and in the [`ReadXml` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml.aspx) implementation, check for the specific elements that you require, throwing exceptions when you don't find them (or setting whatever notification you need to).

If you want to use a schema for validation (to use the [`minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` schema attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref6), for example), then you can configure the [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) instance to validate against the schema by setting the [`Schemas` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas.aspx) on the [`XmlReaderSettings` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyt9ka3c) that you pass to the [`Create` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162473.aspx) (note there are overloads of `Create` which take a [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx), etc.).

Comment: Thanks... I guess I will go with schema validation :)